# Linq Select items where they are before a certain date or the first after

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq-to-Entity query which grabs all the items before a certain date, I was wondering if anyone body knows a way to also grab the first record larger than that date in the same query.

```
context.Items.Where(x => x.CheckDate < DateTime.Now)
```

Is there a way to modify this so that I can grab the first date after without making two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = from u in context.Items
                                 let dt = (from i in context.Items
                                  where i.CheckDate> DateTime.Now orderby i.CheckDate ).FirstOrDefault()
                                 where u.CheckDate <=dt
                             select u;
```

Comment: Will the first or default materialize in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You need two queries, but to merge the results you can use **[concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979(v=vs.110).aspx)**,

```
var result =context.Items.Where(x => x.CheckDate < DateTime.Now).Concat( context.Items.OrderByDescending(t=>t.CheckDate >Yourdatetime).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all of that...

```
context.Items.Where(x => x.CheckDate < DateTime.Now).OrderByDescending(x => x.CheckDate).FirstOrDefault();
```